# Shell / Bash - If I can find the files, how can I copy them over to a mapped drive too?

Tags: bash, shell, cifs

I have a command that will find all .png image files on my linux machine, but is there something I can add to it that will also copy each one over to a mapped drive / location I have set up?

Code to find .png is here.

```
find / -type f -exec file --mime-type {}  \; | awk '{if ($NF == "image/png") print $0 }'
```

The mapped drive on the machine is as follows, as reported via df -h

```
/mnt/nas
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check the MIME type, after your command, extract a file name part by using `sed` and execute `cp` by using `xargs`.

```
find / -type f -exec file --mime-type {}  \; | awk '{if ($NF == "image/png") print $0 }' \
| sed 's/:.\+$//' | xargs -i cp -p {} /mnt/nas
```

If you can determine the file type by the extension `.png`, the command is below:

```
find / -name '*.png' -exec cp -p {} /mnt/nas \;
```

or

```
find / -name '*.png' | xargs -i cp -p {} /mnt/nas
```

Note that I checked the commands on GNU bash only.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit strange that you run `file --mime-type` to determine whether the file is a png. Couldn't you just look at the file extension like so?

```
find / -type f -iname '*.png'
```

`find` uses short-circuit evaluation. If one of its test (e.g. `-iname`, but also `-exec`) fails, then the subsequent tests will be ignored. Therefore you can use

```
find / -type f -iname '*.png' -exec cp {} /mnt/nas \;
```

For faster execution you might want to switch to `-exec cp -t /mnt/nas {} +` if your `cp` supports `-t`.

If you want to stick to `file --mime-type`, use

```
find / -type f -exec sh -c \
 'file -b --mime-type "$0" | grep -qx image/png && cp "$0" /mnt/nas' {} \;
```

Both of these approaches correctly handle all filenames, even such with linebreaks in them.

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust your original command by printing the filename instead of the whole line in awk. Then copy the file with xargs (you can also use the awk `system` subcommand)

```
find / -type f -exec file --mime-type {}  \; | \
awk '{if ($NF == "image/png") print $1}' \
xargs -I% cp % /mnt/nas
```

Note that the print of the filename in awk is brittle because the awk default delimiter is space/tabs. And the filename may contain space.
I would specify the ': ' delimiter since that is which one used by `file --mime-type` (and also not need a `if`, awk has a straight way for that case)

```
find / -type f -exec file --mime-type {}  \; | \
awk -F ': ' '$NF=="image/png" {print $1}' \
xargs -I% cp % /mnt/nas
```

If ":" is used in the filenames you could use any other separator such as `@@@@@`